# PHP - save object equivalent to mysql_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql, object

Is there any equivalent for saving a PHP object to separate fields in a mysql-DB like the function for reading from the DB and creating an object:

```
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'Post');
```

It would make sense if my object looks like

```
class Post {
public $id;
public $title;
public $text;
public $url;
}
```

and the mysql-tabel is in the same structure...

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've learned about PDO and it seems the way to go, generally, but what does it help for this specific problem?

Comment: There is unfortunately no way to achieve what you want to do. See the answer from prodgitalson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isnt. But you could use an ORM like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) which deals with mapping data from a db to php objects and then persisting that data using the mapped object as source.

Alternatively you could write some kind of basic implementation yourself but I personally dont see much value in that.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like [FOR EACH?](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)